# NumPy N-Array Intersection on GPU

Tags: arrays, numpy, cuda, gpu, intersection

A bottleneck in my code is finding the index intersection of N arrays; millions of times.  A simple NumPy calculation with np.intersect1d but running millions of times takes a toll.

An example:

```
arr1 = [0,1,2,3,4]
arr2 = [0,3,4]
arr3 = [3,4]
```

intersection is [3,4]

I would like to leverage GPU threads but struggling on the implementation...
CUDA, OpenCL, Numba and/or other solutions are welcome.

Here is the python code:

```
import functools, datetime
import numpy as np


def run():
    """
    Create fake-data variable `grouped_data` which is a list of 100k entries. 
    Each element has 3 numpy arrays that are UNIQUE AND SORTED.

    Goal: iterate through `grouped_data` to find intersecting values per element.
    Ie, length of output equals length of input, `grouped_data`.
    In each element, these common values will be used to slice another numpy 
    array which is not included here.

    *Question*: how can this be moved to the GPU?  I'd like to leverage GPU threads.
    CUDA, OpenCL, Numba and/or `other` solutions welcome.
    """
    grouped_data = create_data()                            # 9% of runtime
    overlap = loop_through_intersections(grouped_data)      # 91% of runtime



def create_data():
    """ Return `grouped_data`, list of 100k entries. Each element has 3 numpy arrays 
    kern profiler shows this function takes ~ 9% of runtime """
    array = np.array(range(2000))

    grouped_data = []
    for i in range(100000):
        ar1 = array[::np.random.randint(1,9)]
        ar2 = array[::np.random.randint(1,9)]
        ar3 = array[::np.random.randint(1,9)]

        grouped_data.append( [ar1, ar2, ar3] )

    return grouped_data


def loop_through_intersections(grouped_data):
    """  for each element in grouped_data (3 numpy arrays), find the intersecting values 
    kern profiler shows this function takes ~ 91% of runtime 
    """
    overlap = []
    for f in grouped_data:
        overlap.append( functools.reduce(intersect1d, f) )
    return overlap


def intersect1d(ar1, ar2):
    """
    Find the intersection of two arrays.
    Return the sorted, unique values that are in both of the input arrays.

    Taken from NumPy.   https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.14.0/numpy/lib/arraysetops.py#L297-L338
    """
    aux = np.concatenate((ar1, ar2))
    aux.sort()
    return aux[:-1][aux[1:] == aux[:-1]]




####################################################
#            Runtime takes ~6s 
####################################################

st = datetime.datetime.now()
run();  print datetime.datetime.now() - st
```

I'm also open to transforming the input.  For example, I could convert list grouped_data to a matrix.

All GPU solutions welcome.

**

### UPDATE - CUDA ATTEMPT

**

1st update, I converted the data to a matrix (vs list of list) to pass arrays to a GPU.

2nd update, sample data is much smaller now for simplicity.

3rd update, I am learning CUDA and wrote a simple kernel, but the behavior is unexpected...

My kernel should have 1 thread per output column.
For the first thread (value 0), take input matrix columns 0,1,2 and find the value intersection.  If all are 1 in a row, set the output row to 1, else do nothing.

Currently the output is unexpected and i'm not sure why. 
Any ideas??

```
import numpy as np

import pycuda.driver as drv
import pycuda.autoinit
from pycuda.compiler import SourceModule
from pycuda import driver, compiler, gpuarray, tools


def create_data(rows, iterations):
    np.random.seed(42)
    array = np.array(range(rows))

    grouped_data = []
    for i in range(iterations):
        for j in range(3):
            index = np.zeros(rows, dtype=bool)
            index[ array[::np.random.randint(1,4)] ] = True        
            grouped_data.append( index )

    #matrix = np.array( np.array(grouped_data).T, order='F')
    matrix = np.array( np.array(grouped_data).T, dtype=np.float32)
    return matrix



def get_kernel_code(rows, iterations):

    kernel_code = """
    __global__ void MyKernel(int rows, float matrix[MATRIX_ROWS][MATRIX_COLS], float output[OUTPUT_ROWS][OUTPUT_COLS])
    {
        const int thread = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;


        if (thread < rows){

            int col1 = thread*3;
            int col2 = thread*3+1;
            int col3 = thread*3+2;

            for (int i=0; i<rows; i++) {
                if (matrix[i][col1]==1 && matrix[i][col1]==matrix[i][col2] && matrix[i][col2]==matrix[i][col3]) {
                    output[i][thread] = 1; }
            }
        }

    }
    """

    kernel_code = kernel_code.replace('MATRIX_ROWS', str(rows) )
    kernel_code = kernel_code.replace('MATRIX_COLS', str(iterations*3) )
    kernel_code = kernel_code.replace('OUTPUT_ROWS', str(rows) )
    kernel_code = kernel_code.replace('OUTPUT_COLS', str(iterations) )

    return kernel_code



def cuda_attempt(rows, iterations):
    """
    Create data, use gpuarray, get pycuda result. 
    """

    # Setup data
    kernel_code = get_kernel_code(rows, iterations)
    np.random.seed(42)
    matrix = create_data(rows, iterations).astype(np.float32)


    # Transfer host (CPU) memory to device (GPU) memory
    input = gpuarray.to_gpu(matrix)
    output = gpuarray.empty((rows, iterations), np.float32)


    # Compile the kernel code 
    mod = compiler.SourceModule(kernel_code)
    intersect = mod.get_function("MyKernel")


    # Define Thread & Block Size
    number_threads = output.shape[1]
    number_blocks = 1

    intersect(
        np.int32(rows), input, output,
        block=(number_blocks,number_threads,1)
        )

    gpu_output = output.get()
    print '\n output col0 which is the intersection of first 3 input columns\n', gpu_output[:, :1]
    print '\n should be \n', np.array([1, 0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1], dtype=float)


    old = input.get()
    print '\n Matrix Input for 1st Grouping of 3 \n', old[:, 0:3]

    return



cuda_attempt(rows=10, iterations=2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is a solution. Good learning experience.

GPU code is up to 5x faster than Numba.  Not as great as I wanted...
I can still optimize block and grid sizes but will leave for now.

```
import numpy as np
import datetime
from numba import njit

from pycuda import driver, compiler, gpuarray, tools
import pycuda.autoinit 



def compare(rows, iterations):
    """
    Run CPU & GPU Version.  Compare output.
    Creates binary matrix called a_cpu which represents a dataset.
    The goal is to take 3 columns at a time and if all are 1, pass 1
    to the output matrix.
    """

    np.random.seed(42)
    a_cpu = np.random.randint(0,2, (rows, iterations*3)).astype(np.float32)


    st = datetime.datetime.now()
    cpu = np.zeros((rows, iterations), dtype=int)
    iterate_over_matrix(a_cpu, iterations, rows, cpu)
    print '\n\t CPU runtime: ', datetime.datetime.now() - st


    st = datetime.datetime.now()
    gpu = cuda_attempt(rows, iterations, a_cpu)
    print '\n\t GPU runtime: ', datetime.datetime.now() - st

    print "cpu.sum(): {:,}".format(cpu.sum())
    print "gpu.sum(): {:,}".format(int(gpu.sum()))



def get_kernel_code(iterations):

    kernel_code = """
    __global__ void MatrixMulKernel(int ROWS, float *A, float *C)
    {
        const int wC = %(C_SIZE)s;

        const int blockId = blockIdx.y * gridDim.x + blockIdx.x;
        const int thread = blockId * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;


        if ( thread < (ROWS * wC) ) {
            float Aele = A[3*thread] * A[3*thread +1] * A[3*thread +2];
            C[thread] = Aele;
        }
    }
    """

    kernel_code = kernel_code % { 
        'A_SIZE': 3*iterations,
        'C_SIZE': iterations,
        }

    return kernel_code



def cuda_attempt(rows, iterations, a_cpu):
    """
    Create data, use gpuarray, get pycuda result. 
    """

    a_gpu = gpuarray.to_gpu(a_cpu) 
    c_gpu = gpuarray.empty((rows, iterations), np.float32)


    kernel_code = get_kernel_code(iterations)
    mod = compiler.SourceModule(kernel_code)
    matrixmul = mod.get_function("MatrixMulKernel")


    # 2D Grid of 1D Blocks
    needed_threads = rows * iterations
    threads = 1024
    number_blocks = needed_threads // threads + 1
    number_blocks = int(np.sqrt(number_blocks)) + 1

    assert (number_blocks <= 65535), "number of blocks exceeds allowed limit in 1 dimension"


    grid = (number_blocks, number_blocks)
    block = (threads, 1, 1)

    matrixmul(
        np.int32(rows), a_gpu, c_gpu, 
        grid = grid,
        block = block,
        )

    return c_gpu.get()



#===============================================================================
#                    CPU CALCULATTIONS
#===============================================================================

@njit
def iterate_over_matrix(matrix, iterations, rows, bools):
    for i in range(iterations):
        arr = matrix[:, i*3:(i*3+3)]
        check_intersection(bools[:, i], arr[:, 0], arr[:, 1], arr[:, 2], rows)



@njit
def check_intersection(index, ar1, ar2, ar3, rows):
    for i in range(rows):
        if ar1[i] == ar2[i] == ar3[i] == True:
            index[i] = True





#===============================================================================
#                    RUN
#===============================================================================


rows=5
iterations=2


rows=2000
iterations=100000


compare(rows, iterations)
```

Comment: I am not able to understand your output. Can you make some clarifications?